# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'firstName' of 'Person.Person(string, string)'

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, constructor, default-constructor

Ok so I have two simple classes, Person and Employee.

Person:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Employee:

```
public class Employee : Person
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Simple right? Employee inherits person, but there is problem. The employee class is giving me an error that says that constructor of the parent class must be called. Now an answer on a similar question says that I should call the base class's constructor and it will resolve the problem. Which it does.

My question is why should I be calling the base class's constructor when employee class it self doesn't have a constructor of it's own?

A book name MCSD Certification 70-483 says that:

> One oddity to this system is that you can make an Employee class with
>   no constructors even though that allows the program to create an
>   instance of the Employee class without invoking a Person class
>   constructor. That means the following definition for the Employee
>   class is legal:

```
public class Employee : Person
{
 public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

My case is exactly as same the one written on this book. The book says that its legal to inherit and not call the base class's constructor if the child doesn't have its own. Why am I still receiving this error? Even when though I have the same implementation.

Is this 2018 book outdated/has an error? Am I doing something wrong? or a new update in C# doesn't allow a child class if it doesn't call the parent's constructor?

Comment: Does the base class in the example have an empty constructor, too? Something like:  `public Person() : this(string.empty, string.empty) { }`

Comment: @Jimi No there isn't.

Comment: The book is wrong. When you create an object of a derived class the constructor of the base class is called first, followed by the constructor of the derived class. If there is no constructor a parameterless one is created automatically. If there is a constructor defined, then you don't get an automatic parameterless one.

Comment: So in the code shown, Employee has a parameterless constructor, but Person doesn't. Semantically, a person must have a name, an employee is a person, therefore an employee must have a name.

Comment: yes, its an error, i gave confirmed. @iakobski

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this is a typo. Because each constructor of derived type in inheritance should call base constructor implicitly or explicitly.

A constructor like this:

```
public Employee () {}
```

is implicitly:

```
public Employee () : base() {}
```

However, `Person` does not have parameterless constructor, so it is a reason of an error:

> CS7036    There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
>   formal parameter 'firstName' of 'Person.Person(string, string)'

What it is possible to do is to create constructor with default values:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstName = null, string lastName = null)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Then `Employee` class without constructor will be eligible:

```
public class Employee : Person
{
     public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yes its an error, confirmed from their site. Accepting your answer since you are write. Its a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it may be helpful to have a little more context from the MCSD Certification book.

Essentially what you are saying is that you want to create an `Employee` without a first and last name. However an `Employee` is a `Person`, and you must provide a first and last name to construct a `Person`.

In your case, maybe it is not necessary for `Employee` to be a subclass of `Person`.  Do you use `FirstName` and `LastName` for instances of `Employee`?

Comment: The book says that Person's fields like first and last name will be set to null if I don't call its constructor but I cant test it since even my employee class is giving an error.

Comment: This can only be true if the `Person` class has a constructor which sets the fields to null (or leaves them at the default). Without such a constructor, the only way of creating a `Person` is by calling the constructor with two parameters. You can't "not call a constructor" when creating an object, that's what `new` does. If you don't explicitly call the base constructor in the derived class, you are still implicitly calling the base class constructor with matching arguments.

Comment: However good design is nice, I think this question was more about how C# works, so this is not strictly an answer.

Comment: @GrayCat Thanks for the feedback! I am just starting to get involved in the community.